# Output string "helloworld" assembly

Tags: assembly, x86-64

I am trying to output string "helloworld" in assembly, but it only shows "orld", how can I fix it?
Here is my code:

```
.global _start
.text
_start: 

movq $1, %rax
movq $1, %rdi
movq $str, %rsi
movq $len, %rdx
syscall

movq $60, %rax
xorq %rdi, %rdi
syscall

.data

str: .ascii "helloworld\n" 
.equ len, (. - str)
```

Here is the output:
[image: gdb screenshot]

Comment: Would you like to format your code a little bit? I couldn't identify where you put line breaks

Comment: sure, give me a sec

Comment: That looks like as if your output is overwritten by the `(gdb) ` prompt that covers the initial part. May be an interaction with gdb or a problem with `\n`. Run it outside of gdb and/or use `strace`. I expect you will find it works properly.

Comment: I think I understand what you're saying, but what I need to do in specific? I actually don't know what is strace.

Comment: Just run it in a console window, outside of gdb. That should already be enough. Switching gdb back to dumb terminal mode may also help.

Comment: Sorry, but I'm still not sure about that, I am using notepad++ and upload my file to WinSCP, and I run the commands to compile my code on Putty. That's what I've been told to do by Professor, other than that I just have no idea

Comment: That is fine. But presumably your last command is something like `gdb foo`. Instead write `./foo`.

Comment: I'm making an educated guess, but if you have WinSCP involved, you are editing your source file on windows. There are two-problems there. (1) many Windows editors save in UTF-16 with a Byte-Order-Mark; and (2) the default line ending on windows is `"\r\n"` instead of `"\n"` on Linux. Notepad++ was suggested because you can choose a normal `"\n"` line ending. Then just winSCP your file to the server you are using, and in PuTTY compile it with `as -o youfile.obj yourfile.asm` to compile to object, then line to executable with `ld -o yourfile yourfile.o`, then `./yourfile` to run.

Comment: So, my commands were, "gcc -c -g filename.s", then "ld filename.o -o filename", and the last was "gdb filename", after I run these, the (gdb) will automatically put in front, and I can not modify it, like, (gdb)break _start, (gdb)run, (gdb) layout reg, so you mean I have to use "./ filename" instead of "gdb filename"?

Comment: You can skip the `layout reg` that should leave `gdb` in dumb terminal mode. Alternatively, yes, you can do `./filename` instead of `gdb filename` to run the program without the debugger.

Comment: Alright, I just simply changed my gdb filename to ./ filename, and it does work, thanks you all anyways!!

Comment: @DavidC.Rankin: The OP's commands don't link libc.  `gcc -c foo.s` is just a convenient(?) way to invoke `as` to build a `.o`.  They link with bare `ld foo.o` so IDK where you got the idea that libc is being linked.  If you wanted to do it all in one step with GCC's front-end, you'd do `gcc -nostdlib -static -g foo.s` to make sure you get a non-PIE static executable (so that nasty `movq $sign_extended_imm32, %reg64` can work) without libc or CRT start files.  One advantage to the gcc front-end is that 32-bit is just `-m32`, not `as --32` and `ld -melf_i386` separate random options.

Comment: Correct you are, My thought at the time was the lack of `-freestanding` would imply a libc link, but there is nothing requiring it.